# include file from different directory

Tags: php

following is my files directory structure...

```
Config
   config.php (is calling some files too like includes/class.DB.php)
```

Now i have created another folder **Admin** and created new **config.php** (and calling root config file by `require_once '../config/config.php';`)  its loading config file correctly but showing errors on **includes/class.DB.php** .

I hope, you have got my an idea of my problem, what is the way to achieve this, by USING `DIR_NAME/ $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use

```
dirname(__FILE__); // or, if you have +5.3, use __DIR__ instead
```

so if you have this structure

```
includes
    -class.php
admin
    -admin.php
config
   -config.php
```

So you can use

```
//admin.php
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config/config.php");

//config.php
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../includes/class.php");
```

it always aims to the same directory!

Comment: With PHP 5.3 you can also use `__DIR__`.

Comment: @igorw: yeah, going to add it

Comment: thanks for great help, can you tell me why did you use `/../`

Comment: @seoppc: because `dirname(__FILE__)` will give you current path of file you're in, no matter what include path is

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
include(dirname(__ FILE__)."/../include/connection.php");
```