# How to include PHP scripts from different directories?

Tags: php, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [include file from different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041330/include-file-from-different-directory)

I have a site laid out as follows:

- index.php includes include/code.php
- config.php
- include/

  - code.php includes ./config.php
- admin/

  - index.php includes code.php

When doing the inclusion from the primary index there are no problems, however when I try and include code.php from admin it fails to locate and include config.php

Comment: Think about you include/require structure. You may need to use `include_once` or `require_once` here. If you include the _code.php_ into _admin/index.php_ the relative paths are not correct anymore.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options that I can think of:

1. Specify the files absolute path in your includes, preferably using a constant containing your base directory. For example: `require_once BASE_DIR . '/include/code.php';`
2. Specify relative paths from each file. To do this, you prefix the path with `dirname(__FILE__)` to ensure that the relative path is in fact relative to the current file (and not the executed file). For example: `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../include/code.php';`
3. Add your base directory to the include path, and specify the absolute path inside the project directory. For example: `require_once '/include/code.php';`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//code inside admin/index.php
include('../config.php');
```

Comment: This wouldn't have worked because code.php is a class and so had to be inside __construct().