# require_once files from another directory requiring within

Tags: php, webmatrix

This is a big confusing but I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I am using the Starter Site PHP Template in Web Matrix for an assessmnent, now when I move several files such as the files containing the database details, header, footer ect.. into the admin file I am having an issue with my index.php and page.php.

These files use `require_once()` to include several files within the admin folder. However in the admin folder the files being required have `require_once` tags again within that directory.

When I use `require_once('admin/database.php');` the database file has `require_once(somefile.php)` within it. There are numerous files like this being included.

How can I use include these files using `require_once` in the root directory without getting errors like these.

```
warrning: require_once(/Includes/simplecms-config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\starter-ste\admin\Includes\connectDB.php on line 2
```

The includes folder is located within the `/admin/` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php `require` statements will look for files in the current directory and directories in the php_include_path. You can solve your problem by adding your include directories to include path.

You can do this dynamically by calling `set_include_path`

```
$directories = array('/library', 'var/', get_include_path());

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $directories));
```

Comment: Now I am getting:

    Warning: require_once(Includes/session.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\rays-website\scms-admin\Includes\header.php on line 1

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Includes/session.php' (include_path='/scms-admin;/Includes;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\rays-website\scms-admin\Includes\header.php on line 1

Comment: use absolute paths in the include

Comment: Now I am and its working like a charm :) Thank you so much. Answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
Your server might not know where the root directory of the website is. So, first, get the document's root directory and append it to the file name like this:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once "$root/your_file_path_here";
```

---

> Looks like you haven't enclosed the file name within `quotes`. So that
>   line should probably be like this:
>
> ```
> require_once("/Includes/simplecms-config.php");
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the correction however that was just a typo.
I am having the same issue as stated here however the fix doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041330/include-file-from-different-directory

Comment: @shaq Did you get the document root value to include the files? Please see my edited answer.